# ionic iphone screen overlap on page navigation

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am facing one strange issue with my mobile app.
I am using Ionic framework, with angular JS.

> Please Help !!

**Issue:**

When I navigate from Page1 -> Page2 , ionic do left to right push animation. Out of 6 from 10, animation moves in following way:
Page1 -> Page2 -> Page1 -> Page2
or
page1 and Page2 overlap on same screen.

Please find the screenshoot attached.
[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: You just need to add keyboard plugin 

And try setting this  

> cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);